# Object Detection API - How to create an Ensemble of trainings?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, ensemble-learning

I already created an Ensemble for classification (average -or so- of predictions per images), or for Semantic Segmentation (average -or so- of predictions per pixels), but I don't really know how to proceed for Object Detection.. My guess would be to extract all the region proposals of all my networks, then to run my classifiers on the *X* best of them, and finally to average the predictions for all the bounding boxes. But how should I do that with architectures following the [Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/object_detection)?

I guess the regions proposals can be extracted using `extract_proposal_features`, and then reinserted to the model, but the only way I see to do that would be to create a complete new model with its own `predict` method etc, dealing will all the models of my Ensemble. Am I missing an other obvious / simpler method?

Comment: Clarify one thing. So you already have a classification model working correct? And now you want to somehow _extend_ it to incorporate detection?

Comment: No, I already have a few detection models (3: two fRCNN, and one RFCN) working correctly (all trained using the Object Detection API), and now, I want to use an Ensemble of these models, to increase the overall accuracy. Sorry if I wasn't clear

Comment: @pierre.ecarlat i'm interested in doing this too, did you figure out how to do this and would like to share?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the basic idea, yes (the Resnet paper has a good explanation of how this is done for Faster R-CNN).  Unfortunately we haven't released code to automate this ensembling process (and don't have any plans to).  It's possible of course; you will have to manually set this up yourself.